# JSON data key starts with number and cannot be displayed via jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, rest

I'm missing something here in my small js script for displaying some REST API data via jquery.

Here's what I'm doing (the issue is with the ${data.acf.7yr_full_copy}, the 7 is causing the problem. Do I need to escape it? I've searched all over and can't find an answer.

```
$.getJSON('https://www.algaecal.com/wp-json/acf/v3/options/options', function (data) {
  var fullCopy = `${data.acf.7yr_full_copy}`;
  console.log(fullCopy);
  $(".seven-year-content").html(fullCopy);
});
```

Comment: why do you use a template string to pluck a single value? `data.acf['7yr_full_copy']` should work

Comment: Provide an example of JSON please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var fullCopy = `${data.acf['7yr_full_copy']}`;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! That did the trick. I could not find any information anywhere on this. Have a good one!

Answer (score 0):

The template string is unneeded.

```js
$.getJSON('https://www.algaecal.com/wp-json/acf/v3/options/options', function (data) {
  var fullCopy = data.acf['7yr_full_copy'];
  $(".seven-year-content").html(fullCopy);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="seven-year-content">
```